# Flutter _scrollController.addListener never executes

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I followed so many solutions on this, and nothing ever seems to work for me!
I created the listener variable like so:
`ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();`
And then attached it to the `ListView.builder` controller like so:

```
ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount: _posts.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Post post = _posts[index];
                return FutureBuilder(
                    future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorId),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return SizedBox.shrink();
                      }
                      User author = snapshot.data;
                      return PostItem(post: post, author: author);
                    });
              },
            ),
```

and then called the addListener function in the initState like so:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    // set up listener here
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      print('are we even here?!');
      if (_scrollController.offset >=
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        setState(() {
          print('reached the bottom');
        });
      } else if (_scrollController.offset <=
              _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        setState(() {
          print("reached the top");
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          print('were here');
        });
      }
    });
    loadUserData();
    _setupFeed();
  }
```

the `print('are we even here?!');` never shows in the logcat.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: most likely you press hot reload - you need hot restart in that case

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: are you sure `_scrollController.addListener((` is ever called? tried to add one additional `print(...)` before?

Comment: This is what my question is about. `_scrollController.addListener((` never gets called. I don't know why. Yes, I tried to add print statements before and after it, and they got called. Everything in the initState works fine except for that `_scrollController.addListener((`

Comment: it works just fine: `class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      print(controller.offset);
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: 500,
      itemBuilder: (c, i) => Text('item $i'),
    );
  }
}`

Comment: and? do you see any output on the logs?

Comment: no output at all. It never gets inside the addListener function.

Comment: did you run my code **without** any changes? just add it as `body: Test(),` in your `Scaffold` and see the logs

Comment: @pskink I ran your code. it's working and showing the result in the log. I think my code maybe has some conflicts with that scrollController listener. Please refer to the full code here ->  https://gist.github.com/EidarousDev/3fbe18ab6646edac71a0b6de57afe063

Comment: it works if you remove `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: @pskink If I remove `SingleChildScrollView`, the screen won't scroll and shows yellow and black lines saying 'BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 166 PIXELS' and in Android Studio log: `I/flutter (28930): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 1403 pixels on the bottom.`

Comment: wrap listview with `Extended` widget

Comment: Removing `SingleChildScrollView` AND wrapping `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` widget solved the problem!! Thanks sooo much!!

Comment: sure, your welcome